# Visual Studio C++ testing "name must be a namespace name" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

Here is what I did:

I first created a **Win32ConsoleApplication**

Here is the code in it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I add a **Native Unit Test Project**

In the unit test solution, I right click on the  **References** tab, and then add by **ConsoleApplication2** (name of project) reference.

Then I go to the **unittest.cpp** and this is what I see:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest8
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            // TODO: Your test code here
        }

    };
}
```

At the very top I add my own namespace, like this:

```
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace ConsoleApplication2;
```

but then it's an error saying `name must be a namespace name`. Why is this? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you added your file in which you have the namespace defined?

Comment: What do you mean added my file?

Comment: included the header that includes the namespace definition

Comment: What exactly do i add? whatever u see above is the code i got

Comment: Where is the namespace ConsoleApplication2 defined?

Comment: I wrote you an answer explaining what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a namespace that is nowhere defined. In order to use your desired namespace you have to include the file with its definition.

For example create the file *ConsoleApplication2.h* with

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{}
```

populate it with your functions and then include that file into *unittest.cpp* in order to use the namespace:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "ConsoleApplication2.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace ConsoleApplication2;
...
```

Comment: Or just don't `use` the namespace because it doesn't exist.

Comment: then also the question would not exist :) 
He can now populate the namespace however he wishes...

Comment: idk why this doesnt work. i did exactly what you said but it says `cannot open source file "ConsoleApplication2.h"`

Comment: @maetulj Veesha seems to be a copy-paste programmer (at least at this point) who wrote "using namespace ConsoleApplication2;" without actually knowing what it does. Maybe without knowing what a namespace is. As you can also see by his comment just before this one.

Comment: No I figure out why, I was cause I had to provide the abosolute path, when I do `#include "..\bank\bank.h" ` then it works. I had to provide the abolsute path (bank is another project i created)

Comment: so the answer that you're missing the file include was correct. It would be nice if you could accept the answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

Enable /clr runtime support in your managed C++ project, if you want have
using namespace System;